# Excel VBA verify specific formatting in textbox

Tags: excel, vba

How can I verify a specific format in a textbox? I am scanning a label into a textbox that contains a date which is formatted like:

```
mm.dd.yyyy.hh.mm.ss
```

I have tried things that do not work...

```
If Not Format(TextBox1, "mm.dd.yyyy.hh.mm.ss") Then
MsgBox "Wrong Format"
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this simple function to check if is a date

```
Function checkFormatDate(str As String) As Boolean
    Dim Y
    Dim M
    Dim D
    Dim H
    Dim I
    Dim S
    Dim theDate As Date

    M = Mid(str, 1, 2)
    D = Mid(str, 4, 2)
    Y = Mid(str, 7, 4)
    H = Mid(str, 12, 2)
    I = Mid(str, 15, 2)
    S = Mid(str, 18, 2)

    theDate = DateSerial(Y, M, D) + TimeSerial(H, I, S)

    If IsDate(theDate) Then
        checkFormatDate = True
    Else
        checkFormatDate = False
    End If
End Function
```

This returns `TRUE` (if is a date) or `FALSE` (if not)

Just care about the dates like: `02.05.2016.01.10.05` (where `mm.dd.yyyy.hh.mm.ss`), because, you need to trust that `02` is the month and not the day, as `05` is the day and not the month, always appears somebody with a great idea, and change the values just because.

**Edit #2**

Heres a better version of the code:

Tester:

```
Sub testDate()
Dim Check As Boolean
    Check = checkFormatDate2(UserForm1.TextBox1.Text)
    'the textbox is inside UserForm1
    If Check Then
        MsgBox "Is a Date"
    Else
        MsgBox "Not a Date"
    End If
End Sub
```

Function:

```
Function checkFormatDate2(str As String) As Boolean
    Dim ArrayD
    Dim i
    Dim m
    ArrayD = Split(str, ".")

    If UBound(ArrayD) <> 5 Then
        checkFormatDate2 = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    For i = 0 To 5
        Select Case i
            Case 0
                If CInt(ArrayD(i)) < 1 Or CInt(ArrayD(i)) > 12 Then
                    checkFormatDate2 = False
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Case 1
                If CInt(ArrayD(i + 1)) < 1900 Or CInt(ArrayD(i + 1)) > 2050 Then
                    'set the botton and limit year as you need
                    checkFormatDate2 = False
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Case 2
                 m = Day(DateSerial(CInt(ArrayD(2)), CInt(ArrayD(0)) + 1, 1) - 1)
                 'm = the last (num) day of the month
                If CInt(ArrayD(i - 1)) < 1 Or CInt(ArrayD(i - 1)) > m Then
                    checkFormatDate2 = False
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Case 3
                If CInt(ArrayD(i)) < 1 Or CInt(ArrayD(i)) > 23 Then
                    checkFormatDate2 = False
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Case 4
                If CInt(ArrayD(i)) < 1 Or CInt(ArrayD(i)) > 59 Then
                    checkFormatDate2 = False
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Case 5
                If CInt(ArrayD(i)) < 1 Or CInt(ArrayD(i)) > 59 Then
                    checkFormatDate2 = False
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Case Else
        End Select
    Next i
    checkFormatDate2 = True
End Function
```

Use this function to validate if the text inside the TextBox is a date sending the `TextBox.Value` or `TextBox.Text`. Thanks MikeD for your advice. This way is better.

**Edit #3**

As you tell me in the comments you could use the `AfterUpdate` on the `Textbox`, like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()
    Dim a As Boolean
    a = checkFormatDate2(Me.TextBox1.Value)
    If a Then
        MsgBox "is date"
    Else
        MsgBox "no date"
    End If
End Sub
```

Where the `UserForm1` has a `TextBox` named `TextBox1` inside, and the function `checkFormatDate2` is in a regular module. In my case I just send a `MsgBox` saying that is not a date.

**Edit #4**

The same way you can validate the text inside the TextBox when Exit the UserForm this way:

1) Add a button and set the `Cancel` Property to `TRUE`:

[image]

2)And inside the code you put this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim a As Boolean
    a = checkFormatDate2(Me.TextBox1.Value)
    If a Then
        MsgBox "is date"
    Else
        MsgBox "no date"
    End If
End Sub
```

This way, when you press `ESC` in the keyboard or press the button `CommandButton1` you try to close the UserForm and fire the code inside, and test the text inside the `TextBox` and you could do whatever you want, as, don't let the user go away, go back to the TextBox after a message saying what is the right format, well whatever you want.

Comment: just beware, in a TextBox you have no control whatsoever what the user enters; just one blank in the front can give a totally unexpected result to your `Mid()` functions and spoil your `DateSerial()` further down.

Comment: Hey @MikeD I will take you advice. Thanks.

Comment: @ElbertVillarreal  Thanks for the code, I am trying it but cannot seem to call the function on textbox exit. I get an error "Argument Not Optional"

Comment: Hey, check my (last) **Edit #4**.

Comment: @ElbertVillarreal   Thanks very much for the detailed information and your time. I have this working and its exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Try :
If textbox1 = Format(TextBox1, "mm.dd.yyyy.hh.mm.ss") Then

Comment: have you tried that? As TextBox1 does not contain a date, the date formatting will produce an overflow error

Comment: Thanks to all for your help and suggestions. I plan to test and try all of them to better understand how this works.

Answer (score 0):

`TextBox1` does not contain a date format, so you can't apply a `Format()` function using date/time format codes.

One solution would be to split your string into array elements and examine them one by one, e.g.

```
Sub Test()
Dim A() As String, Rslt As Boolean

A = Split(Me.TextBox1.Value, ".") ' load dot seperated elements into array

If UBound(A) <> 5 Then
    MsgBox "not 6 numbers seperated by (5) dots"
    Rslt = False

ElseIf Val(A(0)) < 1 Or Val(A(0)) > 12 Then
    MsgBox "1st part not a valid month (01-12)"
    Rslt = False

ElseIf Val(A(1)) < 1 Or Val(A(1)) > 31 Then
    MsgBox "2nd part not a valid day (01-31)"
    Rslt = False

ElseIf Val(A(2)) < 0 Or Val(A(1)) > 99 Then
    MsgBox "3rd part not a valid year (00-99)"
    Rslt = False

ElseIf Val(A(3)) < 0 Or Val(A(3)) > 23 Then
    MsgBox "4th part not a valid hour (00-23)"
    Rslt = False

ElseIf Val(A(4)) < 0 Or Val(A(4)) > 59 Then
    MsgBox "5th part not a valid minute (00-59)"
    Rslt = False

ElseIf Val(A(5)) < 0 Or Val(A(5)) > 59 Then
    MsgBox "6th part not a valid second (00-59)"
    Rslt = False
End If

If Not Rslt Then
    'beat the user
End If
End Sub
```

This doesn't consider months with 28/29/30/31 days, but that's only 1 or 2 if's further away.